# Convert NSString containing AM/PM to NSDate

Tags: ios, objective-c

Maybe it's an old question and I've searched on this site and found some similar questions, but I still cannot solve my problem. I have a NSString named gameDateTimeStr: "11/12/2013-10:00 PM" and I want to convert it to NSDate. I used the following code:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy-HH:mm a"];
[formatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
NSDate *gameDateTime = [formatter dateFromString:gameDateTimeStr];
```

However, when printed on consolte, its description is: 2013-11-12 05:00:00 +0000

 As you can see, the date is correct, but the time is wrong.
Please help me fix it.

Comment: set timezone then it gives correct time

Comment: `[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy-hh:mm a"];` it's lowercase **hh** for the 12 hour format. **HH** is for 24 hour format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are one issues with you date formatter, first you are using 24 hour format, **`HH`** for the hours in the date format. But you example uses 12 hour format and **`hh`** should be used.

```
[formatter setDateFormat:@"MM/dd/yyyy-hh:mm a"];
```

Depending on you timezone offset the date is parsed correctly, since date printedby `NSLog` is is represented in GMT.

When you create a string form the date object use `NSDateFormatter` you timezone is used to calculate the correct time offset.

Comment: I have another problem. Your code is correct if the iphone/ipad is set to AM/PM format. However, If I change the date/time format (24hours) in Setting app, the conversion is wrong. It returns January 01, 2011. So how can I fix it? Do we have to check which format the device is using?

Comment: It should not, since you are using a explicit date format the user settings should not matter. Only when you are presenting the date to the user will this come in to play. I've tried the date formatter with your given date on my device, which is set to 24 hour format, and it works just as you would expect.